# how to copy a file to clipboard using python (like ctrl+c) windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, automation, file-copying

I want to copy a file to clipboard using python and when I use the ctrl+V pasting should also want to work.

I am trying to automate google lens website using selenium for that I want to copy a file and past it to the website for this automation I want to copy file

I tried using chatgpt bard bing new ai anything didnt workes for me

Answer (score 1):

To copy a file to the clipboard using Python and enable Ctrl+V pasting functionality, you can use the pyperclip library. However, note that the pyperclip library primarily supports text-based data copying. So, to copy a file, we need to read its contents as bytes and encode it as text before copying.

Here's an example that demonstrates how to copy a file to the clipboard and enable Ctrl+V pasting

```
import pyperclip

def copy_file_to_clipboard(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        file_contents = file.read()
        file_contents_encoded = file_contents.hex()  # Convert bytes to hexadecimal representation

    pyperclip.copy(file_contents_encoded)

# Example usage
file_path = '/path/to/file.txt'  # Replace with your file path
copy_file_to_clipboard(file_path)
```

Comment: File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python projects\img text extract\selen.py", line 11
    file_path = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python projects\img text extract\imagetext.jpg'  # Replace with your file path
                                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: You can only copy text , you cant copy file.

Comment: i want to copy a file is there a way

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.